# Webpage not available error

Tags: android, html, cordova

html5+cordova app on android - after signing in to app and accepting, I get the following message: "webpage not available http://localhost/$code=4/" followed by lots of letters "webpage might be temporarily down or moved to new address"--this is a result of using full client id from android app in developer console  I tried 12-digit id only and got a 401 error, invalid_client id.  Using the client id from the web app gives me a sign-in screen but sends me back to my app, triggering "on error" with no message.  My app was developed on Construct 2 and exported to Intel XDK with the Cordova Oauth2 plugin.